# Why is 'token_entry' constantly updated when using saga of axon framework?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, axon, saga

I made up project with **spring boot & jpa(mysql) & axon framework.**

(I used only the Axon auto configuration.)

And, I wrote the sagas of the axon framework as below.

```
@Saga
class OrderSagaManagement() {
   ...
}
```

When I run spring application, the following queries constantly run.

```sql
update
   token_entry 
set
   timestamp=? 
where
   processor_name=? 
   and segment=? 
   and owner=?
```

I simply registered the saga management and ran spring application, **why does the token_entry update query continue to run?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming#token-configuration):

> ...a streaming processor should claim a token before it is allowed to perform any processing work...

Basically, Axon Framework keeps track of the Events your app has consumed by using tokens. And each app has to claim a token to be able to process an Event to make sure it's not double processed in parallel situations, for example.

So, every couple of seconds (you can check the 3 options on the link provided above), one of your app instance tries to steal the token or to extend the claim. This is why you get updates on the table often.